# Select top 20 scores from a table

Tags: sql

I have a table like the following:

```
votes
-----
page_id - long
vote_type - varchar which is either 'UP' or 'DOWN'
voter_id - varchar
```

What I would like to do is get the top 20 page ids with the highest number of votes (UP votes minus DOWN votes).

Could someone help me out with the SQL query for this functionality? I basically want to display a 'high scores' list of most voted up pages.

Answer (score 3):

If you can, it would be smarter to have the vote being a number, i.e. +1 for "UP" and -1 for "DOWN".  Then you could just group by each page, and then do the SUM on them to get the accumulated difference.

For instance, the table looks like this:

```
votes
-----
page_id - long
voter_id - varchar (but should be long as well, though)
vote_score - int (+1, -1)
```

Then just do

```
SELECT SUM(vote_score) FROM votes GROUP BY page_id
```

To get a top N score, just order by the total score:

```
SELECT SUM(vote_score) AS votes, page_id
FROM votes
GROUP BY page_id
ORDER BY votes ASC
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically you need to use a case statement to map the `'UP'` and `'DOWN'` values to `+1` and `-1`.

```
SELECT TOP 20
    page_id,
    SUM(CASE vote_type
        WHEN 'UP' THEN 1
        WHEN 'DOWN' THEN -1
        ELSE 0
        END) AS score,
FROM
    votes
GROUP BY
    page_id
ORDER BY
    score DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Kyle and csl's suggestions, consider storing (and indexing) the final score itself. This will allow you to query against it with an index.